# make valueFormatter from DataGrid MUI return Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I am trying to make `valueFormatter` from MUI's DataGrid to return component instead of value.

```
const columns= [
    { field: 'name', headerName: 'Test name', width: 150 },
    { field: 'updatedAt', headerName: 'Updated at', width: 150, valueFormatter: ({ value }) => timePass(value) },
    { field: 'createdAt', headerName: 'Created at', width: 150, valueFormatter: ({ value }) => timePass(value) },
    { field: '_id', headerName: 'Actions', width: 150, valueFormatter: ({ value }) => <ActionButtons url="/tests" id={value}/>},
];
```

As you can see the last row in the array is calling the Component `ActionButtons` inside `valueFormatter`:

`ActionButton` component:

```
const ActionButtons = ({url, id}) => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <Link to={`${url}/view/${id}.`}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <VisibilityOutlinedIcon/>
                </ListItemIcon>
            </Link>
            <Link to={`${url}/edit/${id}.`}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <EditOutlinedIcon/>
                </ListItemIcon>
            </Link>
            <Link to={`${url}/delete/${id}.`}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <DeleteForeverOutlinedIcon/>
                </ListItemIcon>
            </Link>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

But instead of receiving rendered component, I am getting `[object Object]`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `renderCell` props instead of `valueFormatter`.

```
{ field: '_id', headerName: 'Actions', width: 170, renderCell: ({id}) => <ActionButtons url="/tests" id={id}/> }
```